# Accidentally bought I Savings Bond for $20,000 and TreasuryDirect hasn't credit extra money

Tags: united-states, taxes, government-bonds, savings-bonds

1. Signed up for TreasuryDirect.gov and added myself and my spouse as registrants:

   [image]
2. Purchased 20,0000$ of I Savings Bond on 04/25/2022:

   [image]
3. I received an email next day saying below but still haven't received the refund and it has been ~ 8 months.

> Your purchase exceeds the annual savings bond purchase limitation.
> **Please be advised the limit is $10,000 per series and TIN per calendar**
> **year. A refund of the excess purchase will be made to the bank account
> where the purchase originated. You should receive your refund
> approximately 8 to 10 weeks from the date of purchase**. You will be
> notified by email when the refund transaction is processed.

4. When I log in, this is what I see:

   [image]

I send emails through the website but receive below response:

> Due to heavy volume, we are temporarily limiting our communication by
> e-mail.  **For us to respond to your e-mail, it must concern a pending
> case and it must state your case number in the subject line of your
> e-mail**.

I call them and I wait holding line for 2 hrs but can never reach human.

What is going to happen? Any tax repercussions I will have to face?

**NOTE**: My wife created her own login and purchased Series I Savings Bond for $10,000.

**EDIT**: I & my wife now collectively own I Savings Bond of $30,000.

Comment: I expect they would just decline the transaction, not keep the money, and tell you to resubmit an acceptable purchase. They _might_ instead accept as much of the purchase as was acceptable and return the unused money, but I'd be slightly surprised. I doubt there are any tax repercussions other than those of the transaction not going through.

Comment: You need to tell us how many days it has been since you made the purchase. Has it been 10 weeks yet?

Comment: @EllieKesselman "04-25-2022" seems to be more than 10 weeks ago. At least, if I read the date correctly.

Comment: Regarding your **NOTE:** at the end of your question, does that mean you and your wife have collectively purchased $30,000 of Series I Savings Bonds, or does the $20,000 include your wife's purchase?

Comment: @shoover $30,000 between two of us. Updated post to give clarity.

Comment: The $10K per TIN is enforced very loosely. For example, you can open multiple accounts for multiple entities (LLCs, Trusts, etc) using the same TIN, and you'll get $10K for each. That's actually a documented feature on TreasuryDirect even though it contradicts the clear $10K per TIN statutory restriction. So while you may have gotten an alert, it may end up not being acted on on their side at all.

Comment: @glglgl Yes, I saw that date but was unsure if OP was showing his own screen shots or the default/examples on the website. I'm still unsure, as the examples say John Doe and have a generic aspect. Rather than guessing, it would be helpful if OP just stated explicitly what the date of purchase was, or told us how many weeks he has been waiting. If he has been waiting over 28 weeks (April to late November) something is clearly amiss!

Comment: @EllieKesselman All the details in the post are facts except for personal details. I will edit post to make it clear.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I made a similar mistake, received the same email, and also have not received my funds back from TreasuryDirect. After about 8 months, I actually waited through the 2+hour hold to talk to someone (who was very helpful and pleasant, despite no doubt talking to very frustrated-from-holding people all day).

They said that Treasury was aware of the delay, their system did not allow for automated refunds so their (I assume understaffed) teams were going through the transactions individually in the order they were made and issuing refunds, the refunds would include interest accrued (at the normal interest rate of the iBonds), they could not offer a timeline, and there was nothing needed from me.  The interest is being reflected on the TreasuryDirect site just as with the other iBonds.  It sounded like you and I were far from the only people in this situation.

While it would be helpful for Treasury to provide such guidance in a public format, perhaps they are concerned that doing so would prompt people to intentionally break the rules.

Comment: Thanks for sharing. I am now at peace 